# What is the basis of output order Hashset in Java

Tags: java, hashset

I am trying to print the the content of a Hashset. And it outputs it as  [D, E, F, A, B, C]. I was expecting it to output something like [F, E, D, B, A, C]. Is there a logic behind this?

```
public class TestSomething {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        HashSet<String> hashSet = new HashSet<String>();
        hashSet.add("F");
        hashSet.add("E");
        hashSet.add("D");
        hashSet.add("B");
        hashSet.add("A");
        hashSet.add("C");

        System.out.println(hashSet.toString())
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [HashSet javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html):

> It makes no guarantees as to the iteration order of the set; in
>   particular, it does not guarantee that the order will remain constant
>   over time.

If you need an ordered set, try a [LinkedHashSet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashSet.html)

Answer (score 0):

From [Java Documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html)

> [Hashset]  implements the Set interface, backed by a hash table (actually a HashMap instance). It makes no guarantees as to the iteration order of the set; in particular, it does not guarantee that the order will remain constant over time.

Answer (score -2):

Use LinkedHashSet for expected output.